# Refreshing and Updating Context Menu Strip every second

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on an application that exists only as a tray app that gives you a Context Menu that allows you to interact with a specific windows service. The problem I've currently reached is I need to continuously check to see if the service is still running and also update information contained in the Main() method. The issue I have reached is outside the initial status check I am only able to show/hide ToolStripItems via interaction based methods. I need this to both happen on interaction and automatic time based checks.

My first attempt was a loop that would infinitely loop until the user hits exit. In pseudo code it looks like the following.

```
status = getStatus;
//show/hide based on status
 if (status == "Running")
 {
 _stopButton.Visible = true;
}
 if (count == 0)
{
//when run the first time it starts the application
  Application.Run();
  count = 1;
}
//every second it should check everything however we never end up seeing this part
 Thread.Sleep(1000);
 Console.WriteLine("checked");
}
```

I have spent a while looking into Context Menu Strip and seeing if there was an automatic updating item you could add however that doesn't seem to be the case. All in all I'm currently unsure of how to properly conduct the status updates every second and also have access to portions of the Main() method once Application.Run(); has been used.

Comment: See [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=net-5.0). Create one, set its `Interval` property to fire the `Tick` event every second (=1000), start it, and do the check from there.

Comment: @dr.null this helped a lot, if you want to repost that as an answer and I can mark it as answered.

Comment: It was just a suggestion. You managed to make it work. You post the answer and accept it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I figured out was to keep the loop as I had it in the Main method and then utilize the System.Windows.Forms.Timer. I also needed to swap out Application.Run() for Application.DoEvents(). Working code looked like the following

```
            myTimer.Interval = 1000;
            myTimer.Start();
            while (!end)
            {



                status = getStatus();
                if (status == "Running")
                {
                    trayicon.Icon = Properties.Resources.icon_1x;
                    _stopButton.Visible = true;
                    _pauseButton.Visible = true;
                    _startButton.Visible = false;
                }
               Application.DoEvents();
             }
```